# Will memory upgrade cause downtime on highly available Cloud SQL Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We've a highly available Google Cloud SQL (PostgreSql 14) instance with decent traffic. If we increase the memory configuration, will it cause any downtime on reads/writes?

Will it trigger a fail-over, or will both the master and fail-over instances restart at the same time, causing a complete downtime?

Comment: Why not just ask your Google support line?

Answer (score 0):

Changing/Upgrading the memory involves similar operations to changing [vCPUs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#:%7E:text=Learn%20more.-,Can%20I%20upgrade%20and%20downgrade%20vCPUs%3F,-Yes.%20You%20can). It typically takes less than five minutes of downtime.

However, as the [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq) mentions, for large, heavily used instances, downtime can be up to an hour.

---

You could also check out this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/reduce-db-upgrade-downtime-to-less-than-10-minutes-using-dms-on-google-cloud-8704681e45ac). Hoping that this can help you upgrading your memory.